# Source Safe 6.0d and Visual Studio 2005 project tree problems

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

Whenever I try to add a new project to my SourceSafe repository it creates 3 folders with the same name nested within each other.  There is only one folder on my drive yet in Sourcesafe there are 3??

Can anyone suggest what may be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drag and rop a new project folder into VSS and do a recursive add then that's just how it works. Otherwise you have to create your own root project folder in VSS and add each file one at a time to VSS by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the project in VS2005 disconnected from source control, then creating the project folder in VSS, set the working folder correctly, add the files to sourcesafe from VSS, then lastly edit the source control bindings in VS2005 and check the bound project into source control.

A little kludgey but this is how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

well, that problem comes due to visual studio. because visual stuio by default save solution file in the my documents/...../.../vs 2008/projects/ location and that address is also saved in the .sln file.

that's why every time you get latest within visual stuio it try to creat same strucute and make another copy with in the main project folder.

Solution, well i still trying to figure out how to tackle it.

cheers,
Genious